# Golang: how to cast []string to a typed struct?

Tags: go

With json objects it's simple:

```
type MyObj struct {
    Prop1   int      `json:"prop1"`
    Prop2   []string `json:"prop2"`
}
```

How would I cast simple `[]string` slice against MyObj? I know I could iterate over slice and manually assign each property by respective index, but maybe there's more optimal way, considering that Prop1 references at 0 index of the slice, and Prop2 - 1.

**EDIT1**:

My actual JSON string looks like `[100, 200]`. So `MyObj.Prop1` would get filled with `100`, and `MyObj.Prop2` with `200` respectively.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to cast a `[]MyObj` into a `[]string`?

Comment: Could you also show us how your string would look like?

Comment: Other way around. I have JSON `[100, 200]` and I want to cast it into `MyObj`, so that I could access `100` with `MyObj.Prop1` and `200` with `MyObj.Prop2`.

Comment: According to the MyObj you defined, your json should look like this: {"prop1":100,"prop2":["200"]}. Since prop1 is an int, and prop2 is a []string

Comment: I know how to deal with that kind of JSON, but there's a portion of it which stays as `[100, 200]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a custom `json.Umnarshaller`:

```
type MyObj struct {
    Prop1   int      `json:"prop1"`
    Prop2   int      `json:"prop2"`
}

func (a *MyObj) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    s := []string{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    l := len(s)

    // Check slice bounds and errors!!
    a.Prop1, _ = strconv.Atoi(s[0])
    a.Prop2, _ = strconv.Atoi(s[l-1])

    return nil
}
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/fVobgtrqNw

Comment: Thanks. I see we still have to manually assign `Prop1` and `Prop2`. I was wondering if we had an automated way of doing something like `MyObj[0] = slice[0]` meaning that Prop1 resides at index 0 within `MyObj`.

Comment: `MyObj[0]` and `slice[0]` are different types (type `MyObj` and `string` respectively). The `=` operation you want can not be done. Your best bet is to write a custom unmarshaler with the required behavior once so you can avoid manual assignment every time a json data presents itself.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have your json as a string in a variable (yourString) then you can Unmarshall that into your []MyObj

```
yourString := `{"prop1":"100","prop2":"200"}`
var myObj MyObj
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(yourString), &myObj)
if err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", myObj)
} else {
    fmt.Println(err)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", myObj)
}
```

Alternatively you can do this using json.decode:

```
yourString := `{"a" : ["prop1":100,"prop2":["200"]}`
var myObj MyObj
err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(yourString)).Decode(&myObj)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(myObj.Prop1)
fmt.Println(myObj.Prop2)
```

**Update**

According to the MyObj you defined, your json should look like this: {"prop1":100,"prop2":["200"]}. Since prop1 is an int, and prop2 is a []string 
I think you either need to change your struct or change your json.

For instance you could define your MyObj like this:

```
type MyObj struct {
    Prop1   int      `json:"prop1"`
    Prop2   string   `json:"prop2"`
}
```

To match a json object like this:

> {"prop1":100,"prop2":"200"}

If you want to keep MyObj as it is then your json should look like this:

> {"prop1":100,"prop2":["200"]}

Check in the go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/yMpeBbjhkt

Comment: Thank you. However I explicitly said that I need to cast `[]string` into `MyObj` struct. I know how to do it with `[string]string`

Comment: @AleksandrMakov then I believe that the example I provided in the go playground should work.